# Why Subversive is not displaying complete SVN revision history?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-kepler, subversive, revision-history

When I click Project->Team->Show History... Not all revisions are listed.

[image]

As you may see, revisions older than 691 are not there. Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There should be "Show next 25" and "Show all" buttons in History view toolbar:

https://eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/history_view.php

Comment: Yeah I've found it  @Ivan Window->Preferences->SVN->View Settings->History view-> Enable paging with the following page size. there it's possible to indicate how much revisions you want to display per page. Thank's Ivan I'll accept your answer

Comment: I don't see any of these options in recent (2023) versions of Eclipse. I'd love to now where they have gone to...

Answer (score 7):

This is only the most recent history. Use the marked buttons to show more.

[image]